# Loop through textNodes within selection with unknown number of descendants

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm required to basically *Find and replace* a list of words retrieved as an array of objects (which have comma separated terms) from a webservice. The *find and replace* only occurs on particular elements in the DOM, but they can have an unknown and varying number of children (of which can be nested an unknown amount of times).

The main part I'm struggling with is figuring out how to select all nodes down to textNode level, with an unknown amount of nested elements.

Here is a very stripped-down example:

Retrieved from the webservice:

```
[{
  terms: 'first term, second term',
  youtubeid: '123qwerty789'
},{
  terms: 'match, all, of these',
  youtubeid: '123qwerty789'
},{
  terms: 'only one term',
  youtubeid: '123qwerty789'
},
etc]
```

HTML could be something like:

```
<div id="my-wrapper">  
  <ol>
    <li>This is some text here without a term</li>
    <li>This is some text here with only one term</li>
    <li>This is some text here that has <strong>the first term</strong> nested!</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#my-wrapper').contents().each(function(){
  // Unfortunately only provides the <ol> - 
  // How would I modify this to give me all nested elements in a loopable format?
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following function is very similar to cbayram's but should be a bit more efficient and it skips script elements. You may want to skip other elements too.

It's based on a *getText* function I have used for some time, your requirements are similar. The only difference is what to do with the value of the text nodes.

```
function processTextNodes(element) {
  element = element || document.body;
  var self = arguments.callee;  // or processTextNodes
  var el, els = element.childNodes;

  for (var i=0, iLen=els.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    el = els[i];

    // Exclude script element content
    // May need to add other node types here
    if (el.nodeType == 1 && el.tagName && el.tagName.toLowerCase() != 'script') {

      // Have an element node, so process it
      self(el);

    // Othewise see if it's a text node
    // If working with XML, add nodeType 4 if you want to process
    // text in CDATA nodes
    } else if (el.nodeType == 3) {

      /* do something with el.data */

    }
  }
  /* return a value? */
}
```

The function should be completely browser agnostic and should work with any conforming DOM (e.g. XML and HTML). Incidentally, it's also very similar to jQuery's *text* function.

One issue you may want to consider is words split over two or more nodes. It should be rare, but difficult to find when it happens.

Comment: I'm currently looking at [James Padolsey's write up](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/replacing-text-in-the-dom-its-not-that-simple/) on the matter -- but thank you for your descriptive answer, it seems like getting a complete solution isn't perfectly simple!

Comment: Also thanks for reminding me to ignore some elements - never know what clients will enter in the CMS!

Comment: A serious problem in javascript is trying to write general purpose functions that work everywhere. If you restrict the context in which functions must run, you make life very much simpler. E.g. if you are the page author, or are otherwise able to restrict functionality to only work on words in single text nodes, the above works. But split words over nodes (or worse elements) and you're in a lot of pain. But it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want

`$('#my-wrapper *').each`

This should select all the descendants of `#my-wrapper` no matter what they are.

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YYQZC/) for an example

Comment: That's pretty good... just looking into it a bit further now.
Really should have come up with this myself! Can't believe I overlooked something so simple `;-)`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you are looking strictly for a jQuery answer, but here is one solution in JavaScript:

```
var recurse = function(el) {
    // if text node or comment node
    if(el.nodeType == 3 || el.nodeType == 8) {
        // do your work here
        console.log("Text: " + el.nodeValue);
    }else {
        for(var i = 0, children = el.childNodes, len = children.length; i < len; i++) {
            recurse(children[i]);
        }
    }
}
recurse(document.getElementById("my-wrapper"));
```

Comment: This looks very smart... Not worried about jQuery - but does this have any browser specific surprises in it?

Comment: [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html) Only thing I see is: childNodes - IE up to 8 does not count empty text nodes. It's cross-browser.

Comment: I wouldn't bother with the `el.hasChildNodes()` test, just loop over the child nodes. If there aren't any, `childNodes.length` will be zero so no loop. Also, the second `if` can be an `else` since text and comment nodes don't have children, so either get the current node's text or recurse.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below:

```
 $('#my-wrapper li')
```

Comment: sorry maybe my description wasn't descriptive enough. Sometimes they're `p` tags, sometimes they're `li`'s - with an unknown amount and combination of each. This answer still wouldn't provide me access to the nested `strong` element's contents.